# How to remove property from document?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to manipulate `document.oncopy` property for my tests. And can't figure it out how to accomplish that. I've already tried the following approach.

I wonder why it won't delete the property.

```js
Object.defineProperty(document, 'oncopy', {
    configurable: true,
    get () {},
});
console.log('oncopy' in document);
```

```js
delete document.oncopy;
console.log('oncopy' in document);
```

`'oncopy' in document` says `true`.

Answer (score 1):

The method exists (as a getter/setter) on `Document.prototype`. If you want to completely remove it from the prototype chain so that the `in` test results in `false`, remove it from the prototype object:

```js
delete Document.prototype.oncopy
console.log('oncopy' in document);
```

Comment: Interesting technique. Wonder if it's possible to delete `navigator.getBattery` the same way?